# Javascript active MutationObserver to work on various elements

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers, queryselectall

I want to add or remove `required` attr when the `li` number changes in a `ul`.
If there are no `li`s the `required` attr will be added, and if there are `li`s the  `required` attr will be will be removed.

The function works great but only for the first `input[type="file"]`
I want the function to wort for all the file inputs in the page.
I want it to observe changes in every one of the.

I thought doing

```
const fileList = document.querySelectorAll('ul.file-list')[x];
observer.observe(fileList, {
    childList: true
})
```

but I have two problems:

1. how do I find the array location of the `ul.file-list` I am working at (instead of the `x`).
2. I prefer not to use an event Listener.

Any help would be great.

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
        let liLength = mutation.target.getElementsByTagName("li").length;
        if(mutation.addedNodes.length){
            console.log('added',mutation);
            if(liLength != 0){
                mutation.target.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].required = false;
            }
        }
        if(mutation.removedNodes.length){
            if(liLength == 0){
                mutation.target.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].required = true;
            }
        }
    });
});

const fileList = document.querySelector('ul.file-list');
observer.observe(fileList, {
    childList: true
})
```

This the html markup. This is one of the 27 'ul's in the page I have

```
<div class="custom-file" id="tz-file">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="tzfile">add file</label>
    <ul class="file-list">
        <li><a href="./uploads/9999999/1.pdf" target="_blank"> 1.pdf </a>
            <span class="item-file" id="2018-9999999-21314-1">remove file</span></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="tzfile" name="tzfile">
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't show the page HTML but I guess you can specify `subtree: true` in the observer config (see the documentation) and observe `document.body`, for example.

Comment: I added a HTML example. I think that observing the `body` will alert me about every little change. isn't it?

Comment: Actually I aimed the `querySelector` to the body and now it works great for all the file inputs in the document